# How to debug app when its not already running and activated due to search

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, winjs

Typically to debug an app, I will hit F5 to start debugging it. However I want this app not already running and it activated due to ActivationKind = search. If I hit F5, then app will get activated with ActivationKind = launched. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Debug properties for your Windows Store project, select the option *Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts*, then initiate a debug session.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, Is this snapshot from VS2012? I have VS2012 Premium with JavaScript based store app and I am not getting any check-box like you have. However in my project properties, I have a Launch Application option that have drop-down with Yes/No Available. Not sure if its the same as what you have?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  My apologies, didn't note the winjs tag, the dialog above is for C#/XAML.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771032.aspx#BKMK__Optional__Delay_starting_app_in_the_debug_session) has further WinJS specific info.

Comment: Actually I realized this is the option for C#-Windows Store app. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Project Properties->Debug there is an option call "Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts".  With this enabled, run your application (F5 or however you prefer) and then when you click on the tile for your application or activate it some other way, then it will debug with your currently running debug session.